# Query de rankeamento MMN

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Olá, estou com a seguinte problemática: Fiz uma micro rede-social para os gestores, onde inicialmente o cadastro é realizado somente feito via convite, assim “medindo” a influência de cada um. Meu problema está no ranking que atualmente realiza a contagem dos convites aceitos por cada pessoa e a que tiver mais convites aceitos, obviamente fica no topo do ranking:

```
      SELECT 
          u.usr_id, b.ref_id, u.nome, b.c_hab, COUNT(*) AS qnt
      FROM
          tbl_user AS u
      INNER JOIN
          tbl_user b ON u.usr_id = b.ref_id
      WHERE
          b.c_hab = 1
      GROUP BY u.nome
      ORDER BY qnt DESC;
```

Meu problema surgiu quando solicitaram que eu contasse os convites diretos, ou seja, o gestor mandou para fulano1 (iremos chamar de nível 1), os convites que o fulano1 mandou (nível 2) e assim por diante. É confuso de explicar, mas basicamente um sistema de Marketing Multinível e contar no ranking os convites dos convites, só que não tenho a mínima noção de como realizar isso…

Segue a tabela de usuários para mais aprofundamento nos detalhes:

```
      CREATE TABLE `tbl_user` (
        `usr_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
        #Aqui é onde são armazenados as IDs de quem convidou você
        `ref_id` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
        `nome` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `dt_nascimento` date DEFAULT NULL,
        `cel` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `endereco` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `numero` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
        `senha` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
        `foto` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
        `token` char(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
        `c_hab` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '0',
        `nivel` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '1',
        `candidato` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
        `dt_cad` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
      ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Caso possam dar uma possível solução, agradeço desde já!

Comment: Você não tem uma tabela exclusiva para os convites?

Comment: Não. O sistema atualmente funciona assim:
O usuário "raiz" envia os convites para as pessoas que formarão o primeiro nível e elas vão receber essa tag no "ref_id". Não criamos uma tabela "extra" pois até então não tinha solicitado nada do que foi pedido atualmente, ou seja, quebram toda a análise de requisitos que fora realizada anteriormente... Claro que pode ter sido um erro eu não ter feito essa tabela exclusiva também kk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não pretendo que esta resposta resolva 100% seu problema, mas acredito que o que você deve fazer, para efeitos de registros, é manter uma tabela exclusiva para os convites.

Sua tabela de convites teria referencia para o usuário que fez o convite e do usuário que recebeu o convite. Além de outra referência para a própria tabela de convites, esta última referência serviria para você saber qual o nível da indicação.

Segue o diagrama

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### Tabela usuário

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_user` (
  `usr_id` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `dt_nascimento` DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`usr_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

### Tabela convites

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `convites` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `dt_indicacao` DATETIME NULL,
  `convites_id` INT NULL,
  `tbl_user_enviou` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
  `tbl_user_recebeu` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `convites_id`, `tbl_user_enviou`, `tbl_user_recebeu`),
  INDEX `fk_convites_tbl_user2_idx` (`tbl_user_enviou` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_convites_tbl_user1_idx` (`tbl_user_recebeu` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_convites_convites1_idx` (`convites_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_convites_tbl_user2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tbl_user_enviou`)
    REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`usr_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_convites_tbl_user1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tbl_user_recebeu`)
    REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`usr_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_convites_convites1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`convites_id`)
    REFERENCES `convites` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Os acessórios foi gerado pelo workbench

Comment: Consegui entender boa parte do que você propôs, O que me complica é que me solicitaram isso depois que o projeto foi lançado e bom "bombou". Se não for um incômodo, eu gostaria sim de um diagrama.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Natan, irei estar atualizando todo o progresso para você!

Comment: @WilianSilva, se minha resposta for considerada correta, favor marcá-la como aceita.